# Find the next term

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Here, we have a sequence.

> 0 , 15 , 23 , 155 , 287 , 539 ,  767 , **?**

Can you find the next element ?

**HINT 1**

> These are related to primes.

**HINT 2**

> There are three coins in each pocket!!!

**HINT 3**

> 2 + 3 = 5

Comment: Is $155$ correct? :)

Comment: Are you asking about the fourth term in question? If so, then it is correct.

Comment: Yes and ah ok.. Nice sequence as I'm still clueless till this point xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I define three functions:

> - $p(n)$ is the n-th prime number
>  - $s(n) = p(n) + p(n+1) + p(n+2)$
>  in words: *the sum of three consecutive prime numbers starting at prime number $n$*
>  - $a(n) = p(n) + p(n+1) - p(n+2)$

Those functions produce the values

> - $p(n) = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...$
>  - $s(n) = 10, 15, 23, 31, 41, 49, 59, 71, ...$
>  - $a(n) = 0, 1, 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 13, ...$
>  for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ...$

Then we can express the sequence like that:

> $Sequence(n) = a(n) * s(n)$

Giving

> $Sequence(1) = a(1) * s(1) = 0*10 = 0$
>  $Sequence(2) = a(2) * s(2) = 1*15 = 15$
>  $Sequence(3) = a(3) * s(3) = 1*23 = 23$
>  $Sequence(4) = a(4) * s(4) = 5*31 = 155$
>  $Sequence(5) = a(5) * s(5) = 7*41 = 287$
>  $Sequence(6) = a(6) * s(6) = 11*49 = 539$
>  $Sequence(7) = a(7) * s(7) = 13*59 = 767$

and finally

> $Sequence(8) = a(8) * s(8) = 13*71 = 923$

so the next element is

> **923**

Comment: It is correct, but there's a simple way to find the pattern!!! Try to find it ! ( +1)

Comment: Interesting riddle! Tried for a while, couldn't guess the simpler pattern! Send me the answer, please! solomon.vimal@gmail.com